# In what use case kubectl --api-version option is helpful

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

There is only 1 version per object in k8s 1.20 as can be checked by command:

```
kubectl api-resources
```

Also, creating custom objects with different versions is not allowed. `AlreadyExists` is thrown on trying.

In what use cases providing `--api-version` option is useful then?

Comment: are you talking about  `kubectl api-versions` command?

Comment: kubectl explain deployment --api-version v1

Comment: @xyz, I have edited my answer. Please look at that.

Comment: This question should be deleted. In fact, there are resources with multiple versions, for example Ingress

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```yaml
kubectl api-resources
```

Print the supported API resources on the server. You can read more about this command and allowed options [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#api-resources). Supported flags are:

| Name | Shorthand | Default | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| api-group |  |  | Limit to resources in the specified API group. |
| cached |  | false | Use the cached list of resources if available. |
| namespaced |  | true | If false, non-namespaced resources will be returned, otherwise returning namespaced resources by default. |
| no-headers |  | false | When using the default or custom-column output format, don't print headers (default print headers). |
| output | o |  | Output format. One of: wide |
| sort-by |  |  | If non-empty, sort list of resources using specified field. The field can be either 'name' or 'kind'. |
| verbs |  | [] | Limit to resources that support the specified verbs. |

You can use `--api-group` option to limit to resources in the specified API group.

There also exist the command:

```
kubectl api-versions
```

and it prints the supported API versions on the server, in the form of "group/version". You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#api-versions).

You can also read more about [API groups and versioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups-and-versioning).

**EDIT:**
In the comment:

> No, see example "kubectl explain deployment --api-version v1". In other words: when there can be more then one api version of a resource?

you are referring to a completely different command which is `kubectl explain`. Option `--api-version` gets different explanations for particular API version (API group/version). You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#explain).